# play2-war-plugin Change application path

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In the Play2-war-plugin  [source code](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/blob/develop/project-code/core/src/main/scala/Play2WarServer.scala), I saw this piece of code

```
  val applicationPath = Option(System.getProperty("user.home")).map(new File(_)).getOrElse(new File(""))
```

On my windows server, this is translated to c:\users\myloginuser

I would like my application to perform file operations under \webapps directory instead of users directory. Is there anyway to achieve this by using `Play.application().path()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the user.home param while launching your app :

```
start -Duser.home=c:\users\myloginuser\webapps //not tested
```

Comment: I am running the app inside tomcat, so executing start is not working.

Comment: Try also overriding the param in your application.conf