# playframework 2, getServletContext

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to run my play application inside TomCat using the plugin at https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin
One problem I am having is to upload files to the server. I am wondering if there is a way to get the servletContext and then I can call

**context.getResource()** to get the root path of my application. As mentioned in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112730/play2-war-plugin-change-application-path)

Using **Play.application().path(**) doesn't give the correct path.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for your input.